# NodeJS not letting me import JS to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have setup a webserver using NodeJS, which returns the file index.html. Howevern when i try to import a JavaScript file to my html file, my browser gives the error
`The resource "http://localhost:3000/includes/main.js" was blocked because of a MIME-Type-Conflict ("text/html")`

I do see what the problem is, but i don't know how to fix it.

My NodeJS code:

```
var express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('includes'));
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
})
```

My Project folder structure:

```
/
  app.js
  /views
    index.html
  /includes
    main.js
```

Comment: The given snippet does not include a handler for the file/route you are requesting/the browser will request. You might want to read up on [how to serve static file with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: why not `res.render('index')`?

Comment: @Palladium02 what exactly do you mean by that? The file is sent with the res.send in line 7, or am i missing something here?

Comment: @fedesc didn't know this was an option, it's my first node project

Comment: @TitusTesche this is not a nodeJS problem. it's express. set a views folder and engine: https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.set

Comment: @TitusTesche Your code only handles the `GET /` request to which you respond with the html file. When the browser then parses that file to display it, it will encounter the `<script src="includes/main.js">...` and request that file using the given path. You do not handle that path therefore express responds with a 404 and their default 404 page (thats why it says mime-type conflict).

Comment: @fedesc so do i just need to pass my includes folder as the argument for views? And what about the engine? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @TitusTesche posted an answer with reading source and a simple example

Comment: @Palladium02 alright, i think i get it now. But how would i go about handling that path?

Comment: @TitusTesche I again refer to [how to server static file with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your index.html file and include the javascript file in your index.html file as below it works fine.

The line you have in your app.js file

```
 app.use(express.static('includes'));
```

This is used to lookup the static files like images,js,css so Whatever you defined inside that folder you can use that by including them.

As in index.html file you can include main.js file in script tag. like this:

```
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Use the same server.js file as you given.

Use the CodeSandBox where I have implemented this check at https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/expresscheck-3g9p5k

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .message {
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <p class="message">Hello macho man.</p>
        <p class="message">Check your console after this.</p>
        <p class="message">You may write:</p>
        <pre><code class="language-javascript">
console.log("Hello Console");
        </code></pre>
        <p class="message">and check  if it's working or not.</p>
        <p class="message">Mine is working fine. This is the playground link if you want to check.</p>
        <a href='https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/expresscheck-3g9p5k'>PlayGround Link CodeSandBox</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a **NodeJs** issue but an **Express** setup thingy, which you are using to setup a server.

Serving static files in Express: https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.static

```
server.use(express.static('path/to/static-files/folder'))
```

read also about `res.render()` which renders views
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.render

```
// send the rendered view to the client
server.get('/', (req,res) => {
res.render('index')
});
```

setup your apps views folder where you keep all html views
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.set

```
server.set('views', '../Path/to/your/views/folder');
```

If you decide to use a templating engine other than plain html you'd need to add the following line (this is not necessary if you're just working with plain HTML files - which is the case here):

```
server.set('view engine', 'some_templating_engine i.e pug')
```

Comment: That still doesn't handle the request for `http://localhost:3000/includes/main.js`, does it?

Comment: yeah i got confused by the question and the mentioned problem. added to answer

Comment: Adding these two gives the error "Cannot find module 'html'", is that referring to a missing node module?

Comment: you should remove that line if no template engine is used. sorry i'll update answer

Comment: Getting kind of confused again, i hve added server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'includes'))); (assuming app is referring to my server object instance from express) but i am still getting the error Cannot find module 'html'. Is html a seperate module that needs to be installed via npm?

Comment: updated answer hope it's clear now.

Comment: @fedesc That should work but OP just wants to send a plain html file (which he could with his initial approach). Isn't template engine somewhat of an "overkill"?

Comment: @Palladium02 i know, i asked in OP comments why not use `res.render` and the answer was `this is my first express app` so i drifted and answered about that and didn't notice the actual question. haha my-bad. updated answer to address OP issue but also left the `render()` way since he did not know about it. you're right tho that his initial approach will also work fine. sorry if i confused OP as well :|

Comment: @fedesc i did some research myself and combined it with what you suggested, well i've got a point where it does not throw an error and shows my page, but the js impor error still shows up. I will update my question with the new code

Comment: @TitusTesche about the views - 1) you are now setting 'pug' as the view engine but still have `html` files in views folder. if you still want to work with `.html` just remove that line, it's not needed. 2) about static files - try changing paths to `/views` and `/includes` or use `Path.resolve(__dirname, 'views')` (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path)